# Compiling error when trying to access directory

Tags: vba, excel

The following string of code keeps returning the error expected name parameter and i can not figure out where the trouble is:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="C:\Users\" & user & _
     "\Dropbox (Junior-Consult)\JC - Eksterne projekter\1 JC - Virksomheder\2017-18\Dansk Supermarked - Mapping af kvalitative kommentarer\4. Analyser\" & _
     country(j) & "\Billeder\" & pic_pre(i) & ws_name(j) & ".jpg",
```

This code however works just fine:

```
"C:\Users\" & user & _
  "\Dropbox (Junior-Consult)\JC - Eksterne projekter\1 JC - Virksomheder\2017-18\Dansk Supermarked - Mapping af kvalitative kommentarer\4. Analyser\" & _
  country(i) & "\Sentiment\" & country(i) & "_sent_o_" & ws_name(j))
```

i cant figure out what part of my directory string is wrong?

Comment: You did not provide enough information to get a helpful response. Please list the values of your variables in your question.

Comment: The fact that you are using a `,` instead of a `)` to try to indicate the end of the parameter list is probably the issue.  I.e. it should be `With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(....)`, not `With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(....,`

Answer (score 1):

Your directory string is probably alright. You didn't end the first statement the right way. Maybe because your original string was so long you didn't see it. 
You can use multiple lines using _ like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="C:\Users\" & user & _
  "\Dropbox (Junior-Consult)\JC - Eksterne projekter\1 JC - Virksomheder" & _
  "\2017-18\Dansk Supermarked - Mapping af kvalitative kommentarer" & _
  "\4. Analyser\" & _
  country(j) & "\Billeder\" & pic_pre(i) & ws_name(j) & ".jpg")
```

Are we answering in the comments now? I missed that in the tutorial.

Comment: "Are we answering in the comments now?"  If that was a dig at me (and I'm not offended even if it was), then I don't know whether the comment I made answers the question or not - there is a chance that the missing `)` is just a posting issue (possibly because the OP has other parameters after the `,`?), just as the OP's second piece of code which "works just fine" won't actually work because it appears to be only a **part** of an actual code statement.  I'm hoping that the OP will respond to my comment and confirm whether it **is** the actual issue or just poor question formatting.

Comment: I'm glad you're not offended. I think the odds are good that your comment has the right answer because it is a compile error. On a defective directory string he'd probably get another type of error.

Comment: Yeah - I would give it about 80% probability that it is just the `,`.  If the OP confirms that that was the cause, and you expand your answer to include the rest of the statement rather than just "etc.", (and I notice that those two events have occurred) then you will get a +1 from me.

Comment: I'll take you up on that. Although Tim ruined it.